# How can I find out which capabilities a container has been given?

Tags: docker, inspect

Say I run a container adding a capability, e.g. `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`

Is there a way to find out that this container has been assigned the `SYS_ADMIN` capability?

`docker-inspect` doesn't seem to return such information.

Answer (score 9):

You already answered your question, but to add another option: you might want to find the currently effective capabilities, regardless of which ones you have manually configured. https://github.com/riyazdf/dockercon-workshop/tree/master/capabilities mentions some utilities, which you would need to install inside the container. Example:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine sh -c 'apk add -U libcap; capsh --print'
```

Comment: On ubuntu-based distributions (on mine at least, based on Ubu 16.04) the package is `libcap2-bin`

The command remains `capsh --print` of course :)

Thanks, useful one!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, it is indeed true that posting a question on SO is often enough to find the answer for yourself.

```
docker-inspect <container_id>

[...]

"CapAdd": [
    "SYS_ADMIN"
],
"CapDrop": null,

[...]
```

Comment: Following Macello's, use Go Template formatter: `docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.CapAdd}}' container_id`, `docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.CapDrop}}' container_id`